# HTML Newsletter - Outlook fix for different versions

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I am working on a HTML newsletter/email and have a question regarding different versions of Outlook (2007, 2010, 2011, 2013). The layout I want works on all other clients we have tested (using a 'deliverability test' which displays how it would look in clients).

Link to image of the differences:

http://jimharrison.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/outlook.jpg

What I'm aiming for: To have the bottom of the phone sit on the last 'League point' text.

NOTE: image is set to stretch to 100%.

Outlook 2011: image is just under.

Outlook 2007, 2010: image is sitting far from bottom but the top of the image is aligned correctly.

Outlook 2013: image is way off and also there is unwanted spacing between 'League points' on the left.

Code:

```
<table width="580" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="scaleForMobile">
            <tr>
                <td width="100%">

                    <!-- Column 1 -->
                    <table width="257" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="imageScale1">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="100%" height="10" bgcolor="#ffffff"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="100%" style="font-size: 11px; color: #989A9D; text-align: left; font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 16px;">
                            <span class="heading" style="font-size: 22px; color: #3B80C1; line-height: 22px;">It's time <br>to step it up a gear</span><br><br>
                            Starting on 1st November and running through to 29th December we've got "<span class="heading" style="color: #3B80C1;">Shake It Up Rio</span>" with Samsung offering 34 people the chance to soak up the sun in Rio, Brazil!  As well as having the chance to party to the Samba beat, we also have weekly Best Incentive Points for Stores and Sales Advisors to win!
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="100%" height="20" bgcolor="#ffffff"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="100%" style="font-size: 11px; color: #989A9D; text-align: left; font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 16px;">Sell the Samsung Galaxy Note 3 smartphone and Galaxy Gear smartwatch, as well as the handsets listed below to earn league points and work your way up the league table!
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td width="100%" height="20" bgcolor="#ffffff"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td>

                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                        <td style="font-size: 11px; color: #3B80C1; text-align: left; font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 18px;">
                        Galaxy Note 3 and Galaxy Gear
                        </td>
                        <td style="font-size: 11px; color: #989A9D; text-align: left; font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 18px;">
                        10 League Points
                        </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td width="100%" height="4" bgcolor="#ffffff" colspan="2">
                            <img src="http://jimharrison.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/dashed.png" alt="dashed" width="260" border="0" class="imageScale" style="display: block;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td style="font-size: 11px; color: #3B80C1; text-align: left; font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 18px;">
                        Galaxy S4
                        </td>
                        <td style="font-size: 11px; color: #989A9D; text-align: left; font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 18px;">
                        5 League Points
                        </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td width="100%" height="4" bgcolor="#ffffff" colspan="2">
                            <img src="http://jimharrison.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/dashed.png" alt="dashed" width="260" border="0" class="imageScale" style="display: block;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td style="font-size: 11px; color: #3B80C1; text-align: left; font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 18px;">
                        Galaxy S4 mini
                        </td>
                        <td style="font-size: 11px; color: #989A9D; text-align: left; font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 18px;">
                        3 League Points
                        </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td width="100%" height="4" bgcolor="#ffffff" colspan="2">
                            <img src="http://jimharrison.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/dashed.png" alt="dashed" width="260" border="0" class="imageScale" style="display: block;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td style="font-size: 11px; color: #3B80C1; text-align: left; font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 18px;">
                        Galaxy Ace 3
                        </td>
                        <td style="font-size: 11px; color: #989A9D; text-align: left; font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 18px;">
                        1 League Points
                        </td>
                        </tr>

                        </table>

                        </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>

                    <!-- Padding + (Outlook) -->
                    <table class="eraseForMobile" width="1" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" style="font-size: 0;line-height: 0;border-collapse: collapse;">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="0" height="2" style="font-size: 0;line-height: 0;border-collapse: collapse;"><p style="padding-left: 10px;">&nbsp;</p>                               
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    <!-- Column 2 -->
                    <table width="270" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right" class="imageScale2" bgcolor="#ffffff">

                        <tr>
                            <td width="100%" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="mobileCenter">
                                <a href="#" target="_blank;"><img src="http://jimharrison.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/galaxy_note_3.jpg" alt="galaxy note 3 and gear" width="100%" border="0" class="imageScale" style="display: block;"></a>                              
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td width="100%" height="20" bgcolor="#ffffff"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>


                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue:

Simply removed the width property and gave it the necessary height to fit with the text.

Because it's a responsive email this fix isn't perfect/ideal (I've had to play around with the CSS on the image so that it scales properly), but it's a fix nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<tr>
    <td width="50%" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="mobileCenter">
            ... text ...
    </td>
    <td width="50%" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#ffffff">
          <a href="#" target="_blank;"><img src="http://jimharrison.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/galaxy_note_3.jpg" alt="galaxy note 3 and gear" width="100%" border="0" class="imageScale" style="display: block;"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Difficult for me to test this but it *should* work . . .
I always find putting images into different cells for emails to be quite effective.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!! I have actually put them in separate td's. I apologise as I should have pasted in the fuller version of the code into the original question.

EDIT: full code now in!

Comment: Still, valign="bottom" instead of valign="top" might do the trick . . .